# Proving that if $|G|=p^n$ then $\exists a \in G:|C(a)| = p^{n-1}$

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ such that $|Z(G)| = p$ for some prime number $p$ and for $n\in \mathbb N_{\geq 2}$. Show that there exists an $a \in G$ such that $|C(a)| = p^{n-1}$.

I think that to solve this we use the fact that: $$|G|=|Z(G)| + \sum _{i=1}^k [G:C(x_i)]$$

for some $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$, but I don't see how to continue the proof from here. How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe you have to suppose $G$ not abelian? Otherwise $C(a)=G$ for every $a\in G$.

Comment: That's true @Davide

Comment: In this case also $n>2$ because if $|G|=p^2$ then $G$ is always abelian.

Comment: This is not true even when $G$ is assumed to be nonabelian. There are several counterexamples of order $64$, such as $\texttt {SmallGroup}(64,73)$.

Comment: Forgot to write that $|Z(G)|=p$, already edited the question @DerekHolt

Comment: If you assume that $|Z(G)|=p$, then the result follows immediately from the class equation that you wrote down, because at least one of the terms in the sum must equal $p$.

Comment: Why must one of them be equal to $p$? @DerekHolt

Comment: This you can see by considering the class equation modulo $p^2$. All the indices $[G : C(x_i)]$ are powers of $p$ not equal to 1. If all these indices are divisible by $p^2$, the class equation becomes $0 = p$ mod $p^2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Class Equation yields:
$$p^n=p+\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{p^n}{p^{\alpha_i}}$$
where $1<\alpha_i< n$, because for noncentral $x_i$: $Z(G)<C_G(x_i)<G$. Therefore:
$$p^{n-1}=1+\sum_{i=1}^kp^{n-\alpha_i-1}$$
Since $p$ divides the LHS (as $n\ge 2$), if $n-\alpha_i-1>0$ for every $i$ we have a contradiction, because then $p\mid \sum_{i=1}^kp^{n-\alpha_i-1}$ but $p\nmid 1$. So, necessarily $n-\alpha_i-1=0$ for some $i$, namely $\alpha_i=n-1$ for some $i$.